# A submodule of a free module is torsion-free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am studying for a comprehensive exam and looking at a large bank of problems.  One problem has six statements about module and asks for a a proof or a counter-example of the statements.  I am able to solve all except two related to torsion .  Assume that $R$ is an integral domain and the modules below are $R$-modules.  So an element $m \in M$ is torsion if there is an $r \in R-0$ s.t. $rm=0$.

1. A submodule of a free module is torsion-free.
2. A submodule of a torsion module is a torsion module.

For #1, I know that a submodule of a free module is not necessarily free and I know that a free module is torsion-free but I can't put these to use to find a counterexample.  For #2, this seems logical but again I am unable to provide a proof.  By the way, to be clear a torsion module has only torsion elements.
Thanks!

Comment: Let $F$ the free module, and $S$ the submodule. Suppose $t \in S$ is a torsion element. Considering $t \in F$, what does that say about $t$?

Comment: @Leo: rschwieb gave you two options and you answered "Yes". Also, it would be helpful to state this in the question itself rather than to only clarify in the comments.

Comment: @rghthndsd Assume that R is an integral domain and the modules below are R-modules.  When he first posted the question there wasn't two options or at least it didn't show up on my screen.  Although it turns out my response was wrong.  I didn't see in my question that R was an integral domain.  Also, I have now fixed the question so let us delete out comments so we don't confuse others.

Comment: @LeoSpencer Thanks for clarifying. If they are all domains then things are simplified considerably :)

Comment: @DanielFischer good hint so I think the answer should true for #1 with proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 1 is true.

Consider $r \in R-0$ and $t \in S \subset M$.  Thus, since $M$ is free. $t=r_1m_1+ \ldots + r_nm_n$.  Assume $rt=0$.  Then $rr_1m_1+ \ldots + rr_nm_n$, then $rr_i=0$ and since $R$ is an integral domain, then $r_i=0$ implying $t=0$ and $S$ is torsion-free.  QED

Thanks to @danielfischer for a good hint.

Number 2 is true too.

Consider $t \in S \subset M$, since $t\in M$, $\exists r \in R-0$ s.t. $rt=0$.  Thus, S is a torsion module. QED

I'm not sure how I missed this one to begin with, had a brain freeze I guess.

Comment: But #2 is also clear, right? If $mr=0$ for some $m\neq 0$ in a submodule and $r\neq 0$ in the ring, then of course the same $mr=0$ in the big module.

Comment: yes i meant that I was going to have to still put it here not figure it out