# Is $R[x]/(x)$ a free $R[x]$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is $R[x]/(x)$ a free $R[x]$-module?

My thoughts are yes, it seems generated by {1+(x)}. Is this correct?

I am a bit confused since it seems to have torsion since $x\cdot f(x)=0$, and free modules can’t have torsion.

Secondly, what would be the rank of $R[x]\oplus R[x]/(x)$ as an $R[x]$-module. Is it 2?

Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be free, because of the torsion. Just being generated by a single element is not enough; you need a *basis*, not just a generating set.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ a free group?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: Is $R$ any ring? Or is it meant to be $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @rschwieb Any ring

Comment: @yoyostein Then the logic in the answer you accepted does not hold.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. I am confused. I read that "A submodule of a free module is torsion-free." (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469256/a-submodule-of-a-free-module-is-torsion-free). So, in particular, a free module must be torsion-free, is that right?

Comment: @yoyostein Well, yes, you can read that there, but you also have to read the hypotheses: "**Assume that R is an integral domain** and the modules below are R-modules." So, a general ring doesn't fit this.

Comment: @yoyostein I mean, even if you didn't read that, it's obvious that rings with zero divisors "apparently" have torsion and are free. In fact, it is not completely obvious how to define torsion for modules over-nondomains: there are several competing definitions.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for pointing out the hypothesis, I totally missed reading that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible for any ring $R$.

The right way to salvage the "torsion" idea is to point out that all nonzero free modules are faithful (have zero annihilator) but a quotient of a ring by a nonzero ideal $I$ is annihilated by $I$.

Actually you can go even further to show $(x)$ is not even projective. If it were, the following exact sequence splits:

$$
0\to (x)\to R[x]\to R[x]/(x)\to 0
$$

Then $R[x]=(x)\oplus N$ for some submodule $N$ of $R[x]$. Then there must be an idempotent $e\in R[x]$ such that $eR[x]=(x)$, so that $e$ acts as a left identity on $(x)$. But this is impossible since $ex\neq e$ no matter what $e$ is.

Comment: Why "Then there must be an idempotent $e$[...]"?

Comment: [Basic theory of decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210113/29335).  In general, $N_R$ is a summand of $M_R$ iff there's an idempotent element $e$ of $End(M_R)$ such that $e(M)=N$.

Answer (score 1):

It is generated by $1+(x)$, but not freely: indeed
$$
x(1+(x))=0+(x)
$$
and $x\ne0$ in $R[x]$.

For an element $m$ of a basis in a free $A$-module $M$, the relation $am=0$ implies $a=0$.

By the same idea, no module of the form $A/I$, where $I$ is a nonzero ideal of $A$ is free, because every element of $A/I$ is annihilated by every nonzero element of $I$.

<sup>This assumes commutative rings, but switching to noncommutative ones is exactly the same.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is not a free $R-$module because the $R-$module is not torsion free since $x$ is a element of $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$, but every free module only have a zero torsion element so that is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you assuming $R$ is a domain? $R_R$ is a free module for *every* ring $R$, but it can have torsion if it has zero divisors. Of course, it depends on what the OP meant by $R$, so I've asked him in a comment above. Maybe he did mean $\mathbb R$.