# Left ideal $I$ is a direct summand of $R$ iff $I = Rr$, $r^2 = r$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra

I am stuck on proving a left ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is a direct summand
of $R$ if and only if $I = Rr$ with $r^2 = r$. Could you help me with that? Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Indication : consider $J = (1-r)$

Comment: I added the "ring-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. $R(1-r)$ is your candidate for a complement
2. In the other direction, if $1=a+b$ where $a\in I$ and $b\in J$ and $I\oplus J=R$, $a$ is your candidate for $r$.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this works when $(r)$, $(1 - r)$ are *left* ideals.  I assume $(r) = Rr$ etc.

Comment: @RobertLewis yes that’s how I interpreted it too. What is giving you trouble?